# PHP E-Mailer shows checkbox ticked values as ON, How to change it to YES / NO?

Tags: php, email, post

PHP E-Mailer shows the values `ON` if the box is checked by the user. How can I get it to display values `YES` or `NO`? I've tried few examples from here but none of them seemed to work.

If you could please help that would be great!

HTML Checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="twitter" id="twitter" accesskey="11" tabindex="11" />
```

PHP E-Mail Script:

```
$text_body  .= "Twitter:" .  $_POST['twitter'];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkboxes can't have two values. They have **ONE** value, and that value gets submitted if the box was checked in the form:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="foo" />
```

Then

```
$foo = 'YES'; //default value
if (!isset($_POST['foo']))
   $foo = 'NO';  // wasn't checked, therefor wasn't submitted
}
```

Comment: thanks for that and for the detailed information! :) it has resolved my query!